# Using the image.palette property

Tags: vb.net, colors, palette

There seems to be quite the lack of documentation, at least that I could find, on how to use the `image.palette` property within Visual Basic.

This is something completely new to me, can anybody point me in the right direction? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the documentation is very little for this category, [Exhibit A](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.palette(v=vs.110).aspx)

Like all great things, I recommend browsing YouTube for some more detailed walkthroughs on simple concepts such as this. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w6fvczfcbBU) and [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vP5YtY3NhpE)

Comment: Glad that I could help!